# Assign HDFS location of Hive external table to a Unix variable

Tags: unix, hdfs

Is there a way to get hdfs location from external table and assign to unix variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

1. Run a command like the below,

export location=`hive -e "SHOW CREATE TABLE <dbname.tablname>;"| grep hdfs://`

Please use `after the equal sign on the above command and` at the end. It is not shown here due to Stackoverflow's rich text format.

2. You can check the variable like the below,

   `echo $location
   'hdfs://hostname:8020/HDFS/PATH/OF/THE/TABLE'`

Hope this helps!